# Android duplicate permission

Tags: android, permissions, duplicates, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an app with free and pro versions. The pro version propose a migration assistant to import data from the free to the pro version when a user buy the pro after using the free.

I added a custom permission to protect the free version data. Both versions have the permission declared in their manifest, and only the pro version has the uses-permission.

It works well on pre-Lollipop devices, but on Lollipop, I get a INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION error message if I try to install the pro version when the free is installed. It works if I sign both versions with the same key (in debug for instance), but I didn't on the Play Store, and it can't be changed.

So, is there any solution, or are the permissions broken on Lollipop ??

Comment: IIRC this is a security feature to prevent apps from declaring the same custom permission that are signed with a different signature

Comment: Such "feature" would also prevent creating / using 3rd party content providers, because if your app is installed first, you need to have the permission's declaration :/ ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there any solution

In your case, you may be able to get away with [Derek Fung's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32459818/115145), since there is a clear installation order (few, if any, people will install the free app after installing the paid app).

Alternatively, you can skip permissions, since in this case, there are two apps that need to communicate with each other. You know what those apps are, and you know their signing keys. Perform your own validation as part of your IPC work:

- Use `Binder.getCallingUid()` to get the UID of the calling app.
- Use `PackageManager` and its `getPackagesForUid()` to find the application ID(s) associated with the UID. In your case, there should be just one, and you can confirm that the application ID is the expected value.
- Use [my `SignatureUtils` class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/#usage-signatureutils) (or just grab the code for it) to validate that the signing key of the calling application matches the expected value.

> are the permissions broken on Lollipop ?

The behavior that you want — any app can define any other app's permission — is [dreadful from a security standpoint](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

> Such "feature" would also prevent creating / using 3rd party content providers, because if your app is installed first, you need to have the permission's declaration

Custom permissions are designed for cases where there is a clear order of installation (e.g., pre-installed apps, host and plugins). Custom permissions are not well-suited for peer scenarios, where the order of installation is not pre-determined.

In some cases, this can be worked around by grafting in plugins where they might ordinarily not be needed:

- App A wants to use the provider published by App B, but App A might be installed first
- The author of App A creates a plugin (A') that has the `<uses-permission>` for App B's provider and mediates communication with App B
- App A invokes something on A' when A' is installed (e.g., sends a broadcast to a specific component), so A' can validate that App A and App B were installed before A'
- When the user tries to do something that involves A talking to B, if the plugin is not installed, lead the user to install the plugin

Clunky, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, seems like I will go with the SignatureUtils (again, I'm already using it, thanks!). The links are very interesting!

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you both of your free and paid app has declared permission of the same name like below.

```
<permission android:name="com.example.permission" android:label="test_permission" android:protectionLevel="dangerous"></permission>
```

**Edit:**
For your case, seems you should only declare your permission on your free version. For your paid version, remove the `<permission>` tag and leave only the `<uses-permission>` tag

Comment: Yes I did, shouldn't I? If they don't have the same name they are 2 different permissions, right?

Comment: Answer to your edit : it would require that the free version gets installed first. That should be the case, but it is not sure. And in another context, this won't work : for instance when creating a 3rd party content provider (which I'm also doing).

Comment: @CommonsWare explained it in more details than I can, you should have a look